# Contact button is described by CommunicateAction (schema.org), isn't it?

Tags: button, registration, contacts, schema.org

I have a site for distance education. I have buttons (CSS) for contact and I want to describe it with schema.org with `CommunicateAction` (with `itemprop="about"`):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CommunicateAction">
  <a itemprop="url" href="contact.html" title="Contact us">
  <span itemprop="about">Contact</span></a> 
</div>
```

Is this right? Or is this option for other things?

And - my buttons for "join" for some course are described with `RegisterAction` (with `itemprop="name"`):

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RegisterAction">  
  <a href="join.html" title="Join this course"><span itemprop="name">Join</span></a>
</span>
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org’s documentation doesn’t seem to offer related examples, but according to the [action documentation](http://schema.org/docs/actions.html), it seems to be appropriate to use `Action` types for these buttons.

Some notes:

- You probably left it out for the example, but to be sure: you’d reference the action from its parent type with the [`potentialAction`](http://schema.org/potentialAction) property:

  ```html
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"> <!-- or something else -->
    <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CommunicateAction">…</div>
  </body>
  ```
- You might want to provide the [`actionStatus`](http://schema.org/actionStatus) property, to explicitly state that these are *potential* actions (instead of actions that already happened), but this is not necessary (especially not when using the `potentialAction` property):

  ```html
  <link itemprop="actionStatus" href="http://schema.org/PotentialActionStatus">
  ```
- I’m not sure about using `url` (I think it would represent the URL of the action itself, not necessarily the URL for how to make this action happen). I guess that you should use the [`target`](http://schema.org/target) property instead:

  ```html
  <a itemprop="target" href="contact.html" title="Contact us">
  ```

  Or more elaborate (probably not needed):

  ```html
  <span itemprop="target" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EntryPoint">
    <a itemprop="url" href="contact.html" title="Contact us">
  </span>
  ```
- I think providing `about` for such simple cases is not really needed/useful. A `name` would probably suffice:

  ```html
  <span itemprop="name">Contact</span>
  ```